# xhost + returns unable to open display when run in rc.local

Tags: xorg, startup

I need to run xhost + to allow a python script to take a screenshot. I want to run the script on startup, so I need to run xhost + on startup. I put it in rc.local and set it up to output to a log file, but it output "xhost: unable to open display "" ". I added "export DISPLAY=:0" because there was nothing in the quotes (indicating that the display variable was not set), but it just said "unable to open display ":0" ". I thought that maybe the display just needed time to turn on, so I set it up to run in a loop until the command exits with exit code 0 (which happens when it works) but when I check the log file, even when the display is definitely on, it still is just a bunch of unable to open displays. It works when I just run rc.local, so I don't really have any idea of what's going on. Any ideas?

EDIT: this is ubuntu version 20.10 running on a Raspberry pi 4

Comment: Since `xhost` changes settings in the X server, the X server must be running before `xhost` can be run. At the time `/etc/rc.local` is run, there is no X server running. If you had told us which Ubuntu release you're running, we might be able to suggest a fix.

Comment: @waltinator version is 20.10 running on a raspberry pi